# MYSQL INNER JOIN AND GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

I have a product table that holds product details like name, price, img and etc, and orders table where records orders. On the orders table, I store the only product_id from products and I want to group my results.
For example in my products table, I have

```
product_id, product_name, product_price
1           apple         10
2           juice         5
3           pineapple     7.5
```

As for my orders table for example, I have

```
order_id, product_id, quantity, date
1         1           3         20.02.2020
2         3           2         22.12.2019
3         3           4         12.12.2020
4         1           2         12.02.2020
```

I want to GROUP my ORDERS table by product name and quantity
For example

```
product_name, quantity, price
apple         5         50
pineapple     6         45
```

And here is my query

```
SELECT 
products.product_id, 
products.product_name,
products.product_price AS price,
orders.quantity AS col,
orders.by_date,
(SELECT SUM(price * col)) AS total
FROM products
INNER JOIN orders ON products.product_id = orders.product_id
GROUP BY products.product_id,   
     products.product_name,
     orders.order_id
```

And the result is not as excepted

I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. Do I need to do a subquery?

Comment: Query has this: `orders.by_date,` and orders table has: `date`, not `by_date`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  p.product_name,
  SUM(o.quantity) AS quantity,
  SUM(o.quantity * p.product_price) AS price
FROM products p
INNER JOIN orders o
ON p.product_id = o.product_id
GROUP BY 
  p.product_name
```

The above should be sufficient to produce the result

```
roduct_name, quantity, price
apple         5         50
pineapple     6         45
```

Answer (score 1):

First aggregate in the table `orders` and then join to products:

```
SELECT 
  p.product_id, 
  p.product_name,
  o.quantity,
  o.quantity * p.product_price AS price
FROM products p INNER JOIN(
  SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS quantity
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY product_id
) o ON o.product_id = p.product_id
```

See the demo.
Results:

```
| product_id | product_name | quantity | price |
| ---------- | ------------ | -------- | ----- |
| 1          | apple        | 5        | 50    |
| 3          | pineapple    | 6        | 45    |
```

Comment: yours also working like a charm thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

No subquery needed...

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name
  , SUM(o.quantity)
  , SUM(o.quantity) * p.product_price AS price
FROM products AS p 
INNER JOIN orders AS o
ON p.product_id = o.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id, p.product_name, p.price
;
```